# RxJs Subject let handle new Subscription first

Tags: rxjs, subject

is there a possibility on RxJs Subject/Observers to "shift" a new Subscription instead of "push" one`?
In other words to let handle certain new Subscriptions before the old ones?

e.g.:

```
subject = Subject();

a = subject.subscribe();
b = subject.subscribe();
bx = subject.subscribe(); // <= let it handle first.
c = subject.subscribe();

subject.next() 
// => usually: handles a, b, bx, c
// => I want: handles bx, a, b, c
```

The reason for this is a revalidation function which needs to be called before default handling is called which possibly is adding an another subscription like `bx`

With this normal order of handling I got an second unneccasary `bx` handling.
Its hard to explain it in detail, so I hope its understandable like this.

Comment: No, I don't think there's any easy solution to this. I'm not even sure it's correct to expect such behavior.

Comment: Depending on the desired behaviour, you may simply need to `pipe` on your revalidation logic to the Subject directly